# In a Jenkins pipeline, why is this not showing the return string?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following scriptive pipeline that adds a tag to an existingt ECR image in AWS

```
node("linux") {
    stage("test") {
        docker.withRegistry("https://0123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "myCreds") {
            String rc = null
            sh """
                aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name repo-name --image-ids imageTag=1.0.286 --query images[].imageManifest --output text > manifest.json
                cat manifest.json
            """
            try {
                rc = sh(script: """
                          aws ecr put-image --repository-name repo-name --image-tag qa-1.0.286 --image-manifest file://manifest.json
                         """,
                         returnStdout: true).trim()
            }
            catch(err) {
                println "rc=$rc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the pipeline, I get this in the console output.

```
+ aws ecr put-image --repository-name repo-name --image-tag qa-1.0.286 --image-manifest file://./manifest.json

An error occurred (ImageAlreadyExistsException) when calling the PutImage operation: Image with digest 'sha256:ff44828207c7c7df75a8be2e08057da438b4b7f3063acab34ea7ebbcb7dd50a6' and tag 'qa-1.0.286' already exists in the repository with name 'repo-name' in registry with id '0123456789'
[Pipeline] echo
rc=null
```

Why is `rc=null` instead of the `An error occurred...` string above it in the console output? I've used this way to capture a shell script outputs, but why doesn't it work here? What's the proper way to do it in this case?

Comment: `rc` will have the output, none in this case. `err` will hold a failure reason. Try ```println "rc=${rc}, err=${err}"```

Comment: @MaratC, you mean`rc` have the output if it succeeded? `err` is simply the return code. I see `rc=null, err=hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 255`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the shell step captures `standard output` and the aws client prints the message into `standard error`

You can forward the stderr into stdout with `2>&1` at the end of your command, for example:

`aws ecr put-image --repository-name repo-name --image-tag qa-1.0.286 --image-manifest file://manifest.json 2>&1`

But the other problem is that when the command inside `sh` fails, it throws an exception and it doesn't assign the value to the variable, so you need to make sure, that the command always succeeds, for example with adding `|| :` (execute an empty command if the previous command fails)

The downside is that you will need to check the output variable to check if the command failed.

The snippet could then look like this:

```
String rc = null
sh """
    aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name repo-name --image-ids imageTag=1.0.286 --query images[].imageManifest --output text > manifest.json
    cat manifest.json
"""

rc = sh(script:
"""
    aws ecr put-image --repository-name repo-name --image-tag qa-1.0.286 --image-manifest file://manifest.json 2>&1 || :
""", returnStdout: true).trim()

if (rc.contains("error occurred")) {
// the command invocation failed
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I want to check the content on `rc` anyway on only fail if it contains other errors.